Node.JS - Why is the cookies / session missing sometimes after the payment gateway
I am doing a webiste using Node.JS and it including a payment features where it will post form submission using javascript from ejs file, and then being redirect to the payment gateway.After the payment, the payment gateway will post a form submission to my app route.
Yet, the cookies and session have the chance of missing for the post route. Did anyone meet this issue and how could I solve that.
For your information, I am using express-session (not sure the difference between express-session and cookie-session) and the setting for the cookie is:
app.use(session({

    secret: '1234567890',

    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hour  
    }
}));

